# How to make method, that finds sepcific type of child user control, more generic?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, visualtreehelper

I have some few cases in my WPF application that requires me to find a specific type of user control in a given user control. For example I'm having the following method that already works nicely:

```
    public static System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox FindChildCheckBox(DependencyObject d)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chkBox = d as System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox;

            if (d != null && chkBox == null)
            {
                int count = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    chkBox = FindChildCheckBox(System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i));
                    if (chkBox != null)
                        break;
                }
            }

            return chkBox;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This method will help me to find a CheckBox in a given ListViewItem which allows me to check/uncheck the said CheckBox more conveniently.

However, I'd like to have this method more generic like for example:

```
public static T FindChildUserControl<T>(DependencyObject d)
```

Unfortunately I do not see how I can get this work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `CheckBox` with `T`? Should be that simple actually.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it is not as simple as that :-/ The compiler will given me some few 'Cannot convert' errors that I do not know how to resolve.

Comment: probably missing the type constraint, see below.

Comment: (Just fixed a typo in the code, now it works)

Comment: What, if you have more then one CheckBox/SearchedControl children?

Comment: Should only be a small adjustment, I'll add some code in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `CheckBox` with `T` and add a generic restraint (`where`) to the type argument.

> For example I'm having the following method that already works nicely

Which is odd, as far as I can tell it would only work on nested CheckBoxes. This should on any combination of controls:

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (d is T)
        return (T)d;

    int count = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = FindChild<T>(System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i));
        if (child != null)
            return (T)child;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
CheckBox check = FindChild<CheckBox>(parent);
```

---

To get **all** children of a certain type, this should work nicely:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (d is T)
        yield return (T)d;

    int count = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        foreach (T child in FindChildren<T>(System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i)))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(CheckBox c in FindChildren<CheckBox>(parent))
```

---

> This method will help me to find a CheckBox in a given ListViewItem which allows me to check/uncheck the said CheckBox more conveniently.

You should use MVVM instead. Walking down the VisualTree is a **really** hacky workaround.

Comment: This seems to work fine and I have to admit it look plain simple, however it was once again the details that I was struggeling with.
As for your hint about 'walking down the VisualTree': I use this code to only fix a small problem in the view, the ViewModel will not be affected so I think I should be fine.